# WSO2IS access token always invalid

Tags: oauth-2.0, spark-java, wso2-identity-server

I've built a simple webapplication using [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/) and [pac4j](http://www.pac4j.org/index.html). It is supposed to authenticate users with WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0, using the OAuth 2 "Authorization Code Grant".

The OAuth flow seems to work fine, but not completely:

- user is redirected to WSO2 (`/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=foo&redirect_uri=bar&scope=openid&prompt=consent`)
- user identifies with username / password
- user gives consent to exchange claims with my webapplication
- my webapplication exchanges the *code* it receives for an *access token* and a *refresh token*

**However**, finally pac4j retrieves the user profile (`/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid`), using the *access token*. This always gives me the response

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Access token validation failed"}
```

And WSO2 logs

> TID: [0] [IS] [2018-03-14 16:20:30,446] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.user.OpenIDConnectUserEndpoint} -  org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.user.UserInfoEndpointException: Access token validation failed {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.user.OpenIDConnectUserEndpoint}

The *access token* is still present in the `IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN` database table:

```
TIME_CREATED            VALIDITY_PERIOD TOKEN_STATE TOKEN_STATE_ID
------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-03-14 10:40:35.940 3600000         ACTIVE      NONE
```

I don't understand why WSO2 says my *access token* is invalid.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Try to find a reason in the logs. Looking at the [WSO2 sources](https://github.com/wso2-attic/carbon-identity/blob/7a421e21941ff48914115f772d01027766f556a5/components/oauth/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/validators/TokenValidationHandler.java#L353), there should be a debug message from TokenValidationHandler.buildClientAppErrorResponse() method.

Comment: The only logging WSO2 gives is already included in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, strange as it is... Deleting all *access tokens* and *authorization tokens* in the WSO2 database resolved the issue.